# ssrs 2008 programmatically add tables rows

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

[image]

Above is how my report looks, the part in yellow in hidden, and is only shown when the user clicks the + icon on the [name].    the result is basically the percentage difference from the Past [X]  - [TERM]    i.e  there is a dropdown with, [weeks, months, days, hours]  and a textbox of qty.

so choosing  qty = 4  and term = weeks  will delivery a result set spread over 4 weeks based on the parent result sets date range and name ID

I wish to populate here the number of rows, dependant on the value set by the user
and the data will be from a dataset.

1. Is it possible to dynamically add more sub rows ( like on row data bound )
2. if my first row is ID 123 [name], is it possible to send this value [123] to a dataset
   in order that all subrows are only relevant to the name with ID of 123?

this is my first bash at SSRS so please no half cut answers, that just lead to more questions about the answer given :-)   if this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused about question 1. Why would you want to add more sub rows yourself? SSRS will add rows if there's more data for you, so if changing the @Term parameter leads to more rows in the dataset there will be more rows in the tablix. Could you perhaps post a sample dataset query and how you use the parameters in those, perhaps with some sample results as well?

Comment: i found out that you can create a sub query, and pass the subquery a param from the parent query

Answer (score 1):

Did some research and the following solves this problem.

Create query as normal,  create a sub query, add sub query to table
set sub query param/s as values from original / parent query

alas you have auto-generated columns, for extra queries based on data from the 
original.

I found that this seems to be a good resource at explaining things better:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195017/SSRS-Series-Part-II-Working-with-Subreports-DrillD